# How to use the update API in elastic search query for updating the data in the data set

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

How to add a new data field to an existing dataset using Update API in elsticsearch. For example if dataset already contains fields like `id` but now I need to add a new field name `Name` and pass a value `A`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to add for example an email field to your existing index

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

refrence:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html